# Get Request Authorization token after running selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, authorization, token

I am creating an app with python and selenium, I want to get the Authorization token from the request headers after logging in to the page.

```py
from selenium import Chrome      
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
# For using sleep function because selenium  
# works only when the all the elemets of the  
# page is loaded. 
import time  

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

if not (showUI):
    options.add_argument('headless')
    options.add_argument('window-size=1920x1080')
    options.add_argument("disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--log-level=3")
options.add_argument("'verify_ssl': False")
#Path to your chrome profile
options.add_argument("user-data-dir="+chromeProfilePath)
browser = Chrome()

url = 'https://example.com'
browser.get(url) 

user = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Username"]') 

# Enter User Name 
user.send_keys('USER') 

password = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="Password"]') 

password.send_keys('PASSWORD')
password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

after this part of code, I am logged in the site. now I need the Authorization token for sending requests. How can I get the requests header?